How to achieve ssl pinning or ssl certificate pinning in ionic 3 angular 5 application for both IOS and ANDROID
I have found 2 solution for achieving the above one
1] for ANDROID
          Pining SHA-256 Public key in network_security_confile.xml file
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <network-security-config>
          <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourserver.com</domain>
          <pin-set expiration="2025-01-01">
          <pin digest="SHA-256">HYrCjnv1DYq5Fjy3cgMScHZbpFMKoLQaUBQ39fxztmE=</pin>
          </pin-set>
         </domain-config>
       </network-security-config>

2]for IOS
Plugin: $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http@4
after installing and importing they have mentioned that pin the certificate for ios like this
**step:1 **
1]Importing that http in my app.module.ts file adding http in my provider
a]import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http'
   b] providers: [
                 StatusBar,
                 SplashScreen,
              HTTP,
                  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
               ]
 2]Place your .cer files in the www/certificates directory of your Ionic project.

step:2
        constructor(private http: HTTP, private platform: Platform) {
              this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
                   // Enable SSL pinning
                    this.http.setServerTrustMode('pinned');
                    this.http.setPinningMode('default');

              }
            });
            }

SSL PINNING for IOS
After adding that code snippet I am getting error like when I hover on setServerTrustMode and setPinningMode. Property 'setServerTrustMode' does not exist on type 'HTTP'  and  Property 'setPinningMode' does not exist on type 'HTTP'
currently it is not working , If there any other sufficient  method is there please let me know that....
